# django: invoking browser's save as from an ajax invoked view

Tags: ajax, django, http

In my django app I want to both render a template and invoke the browser's save as. I’ve implemented this using ajax – I have a view that renders a template. In that template is some javascript that invokes another view with ajax. That view returns a response that should trigger the save as. But when returned from the ajax invoked view it does not. If I invoke the same view by cutting and pasting the URL generated by the ajax call into my browser’s address bar the save as is invoked, but when called from ajax it is not. I have verified from the python side using pdb that the view is invoked and the proper response is being returned. I have verified from the browser side that it received the response.

This is the response I return (cut and pasted from the browser's debug window):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 26 Mar 2013 13:07:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0f DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.6.7
Vary: Cookie
Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=SF69.xml
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Any idea why that could be happening? Why would this behave differenly when being returned from ajax vs. 'normal' way?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest/“AJAX” is especially designed for _background_ requests – requests whose responses are handled _by the script itself_, and _not_ by bothering the user directly via the UI. AJAX is just the wrong tool for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by 'handled by the script itself'. If ajax is the wrong tool what would you suggest for achieving what I need to do?

Comment: Anything you request via AJAX “lands” in your script – it’s your scripts responsibility to handle that data, the browser’s UI does not get involved. If the data can be accessed via GET, then just assign the address to `location.href` to trigger the download. If it needs parameters passed via POST, generate a (hidden) form and submit that.